# context menu in angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using Angular UI grid, heres my code:

```
$scope.gridOptions1 = {
        enableSorting: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        exporterMenuCsv: false,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
         enableSorting: true,
columnDefs: [
      { field: 'serverTime',headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, cellFilter: 'date:\'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss\'',width: '40%', minWidth: 50, width: 120,maxWidth:143,displayName:'Récéption',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'varTime',headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, cellFilter: 'date:\'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss\'',width: '40%', minWidth: 50, width: 120,maxWidth:143,displayName:'GPS Date',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'communication',headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader,width: '8%', minWidth: 10, width: 46,maxWidth:60,displayName:'Comm',cellClass: 'gridField'},

      { field: 'type',headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader,width: '10%', minWidth: 10, width: 44,maxWidth:47,displayName:'Type',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'name',headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader,width: '15%', minWidth: 10, width: 56,maxWidth:200,displayName:'ID',cellClass: 'gridField'},

]

 };
```

what i want to do is, when I click a right click on a cell i want a context menu to appear.is anyone here has any suggestions??